# New line in Bootbox Alert box

Tags: javascript, java, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make a new line in my Bootbox Alert Box. I know in Javascript you can use `\n` but this doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have tried:

```
bootbox.alert("Hello \n world");
```

Comment: Could you add the code you've tried already?

Comment: You should mark the below answer as accepted, @user3399863. Pay it forward. :o)

Answer (score 27):

You can use html for that:

```
bootbox.alert("Hello <br> world!");
```

Will do it

Comment: Quite obvious ... but I did not think about it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

with confirm message

```js
$(function () {
    $(".confirm").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm({
            message: "<h3>Hello</h3> <br> world!",
            buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'yes',
                className: 'btn-success'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'no',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result)
                console.log('yes');
        }
        });
        
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.example.com/" action="deleteElement" class="btn btn-danger confirm">Delete</a>
```