# Laravel ajax validation - list all errors in alert

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

With this code i get each validation error as a single alert:

```
$.ajax({
    type: myMethod,
    url: myRoute,
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}" },
    data: form.serializeArray(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('validated!');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        for (error in errors) {
            alert(errors[error][0]);
        }
        console.log(errors);
    }
});
```

So if there are 3 errors user would  have to click to close all 3 of them and i would like to alert the error messages in one single alert.

How can i group them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way would be to store them in an array and alert it.

e.g.

```
error: function(data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        var errorsArr = [];
        for (error in errors) {
            errorsArr.push(errors[error][0]);
        }
        alert(errorsArr);
        console.log(errors);
    }
```

By default `alert` of array would show comma separated string. Incase you want each error on new line, try `alert(errorsArr.join("\n"))`

Comment: alert(errorsArr.join("\n")); this prints it out all comma separated. I would really like to have each error on a single line....how to do that?

Comment: Could you copy the result in the alert?

Comment: Oh now i know what is the problem. I am using bootbox.js plugin and it looks like this: https://s30.postimg.org/pi66w8lpt/Capture.png but if i use just alert(); it prints it each on a new line

Comment: Try to change `.join("\n")` to `.join("<br/>")`

Comment: Yes i found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322614/new-line-in-bootbox-alert-box Thank you!